# Firefox HTTPS 404 errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, iis

I'm currently running Firefox 42 on Windows 10 and I noticed when trying to access my local site through IIS (Windows 10) using a self signed certificate, I get intermittent errors for js, css etc. Eventually they load but very slowly, I get aborted messages in Firebug.

Sometimes the page loads without errors, other times it hangs for a while.
I've tried disabling the cache as well but the issue continues

This issue doesn't occur in IE or Chrome.
If I load the site using HTTP there are no errors.

Notice how site.css is loaded, but there also an error version of it
[image]

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: it can be for your vpn and firewall options. chrome uses ie for lan settings.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today while **not** using Fiddler. I had had Fiddler running, thereby changing my system proxy, and then shut it down and rebooted. When the machine booted back up I started getting a 404 in Firefox (but not in Edge or Chrome).

My fix was to go to `Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Under "Connection" click "Settings" > toggle "Configure Proxies to Access the Internet" to "No proxy", Save, toggle it back to "Use system proxy settings" and Save again` and voila! it worked. I think the proxy setting just gets "stuck" and you have to force it to reset. YMMV

Comment: Thank you so much I will definitely check this out and see if it indeed works :)